# Doubts in JavaScript RegExp and String.replace() method

Tags: javascript

I am trying to enter 'username' in a webpage using VBA. So in the source code of the webpage, there are some modifications done to the 'username' value.

I have attached the code,

```
function myFunction()        
   {
    document.str.value = "Abc02023";
    document.str.value  = document.str.value.toUpperCase();
    pattern = new RegExp("\\*", "g");
    document.str.value = document.str.value.replace(pattern, "");
    document.str.value = document.str.value.replace(/^\s+/, "");
    document.str.value = document.str.value.replace(/\s+$/, "");
   }
```

I read about these and from my understanding, after the modifications document.str.value is **ABC02023**.
Obviously I am wrong as there would not be no point in doing all these modifications then. Also, I am getting an 'incorrect username error'.

So can anybody please help me to understand these. **What would be the value of document.str.value and how did you figure it out?** I am new to JavaScript so please forgive me if I am being too slow...

Comment: it's be `ABC02023` - because you toUpperCase it, and none of the regexp's will alter it - p.s. the last two replaces can be changed to `.trim`

Comment: note: your code will fail, unless you add an object to `document` called `str`

Comment: @Jaromanda X I have an object called str..and I have changed it to .trim.But for some reason I am getting an 'username error'

Comment: `username error` clearly you are, because `username` is littered throughout the code you posted - not sure of the relevance of your statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using some very old code to learn from. ☹
Let's see if we can still learn something by bringing this code up to date, then you go find some newer learning materials. Here is a well-written book series with free online versions available: [You Don't Know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS).

```
function myFunction() {

    // Assuming your code runs in a browser, `document` is equal to the
    // global object. So if in a browser and somewhere outside the function
    // a variable `str` has been created, this will add an attribute `value`
    // to `str` and set the value of `str.value` to 'Abc02023'. If there is 
    // no already existing object `document` (for instance not running in 
    // a browser) or if document does not have an already created property
    // called`str` then this will throw a TypeError because you cannot add 
    // a property to `undefined`.

    document.str.value = "Abc02023";

    // You probably were just trying to create a new variable `str` so let's
    // just start over
}
```

Second try

```
function myFunction() {
    // create a variable `str` and set it to 'Abc02023'

    var str = "Abc02023";

    // Take value of str and convert it to all capital letters
    //   then overwrite current value of str with the result.
    //   So now `str === 'ABC02023'

    str  = str.toUpperCase();

    // Create a regular expression representing all occurences of `*`
    //   and assign it to variable `pattern`.

    var pattern = new RegExp("\\*", "g");

    // Remove all instances of our pattern from the string. (which does not
    // affect this string, but prevents user inputting some types of bad
    // strings to hack your website.

    str = str.replace(pattern, "");

    // Remove any leading whitespace form our string (which does not
    //  affect this string, but cleans up strings input by a user).

    str = str.replace(/^\s+/, "");

    // Remove any trailing whitespace form our string (which does not
    //  affect this string, but cleans up strings input by a user).

    str = str.replace(/\s+$/, "");

    // Let's at least see our result behind the scenes. Press F12 
    //  to see the developer console in most browsers.

    console.log("`str` is equal to: ", str );
}
```

Third try, let's clean this up a little:

```
// The reason to use functions is so we can contain the logic 
//  separate from the data. Let's pull extract our data (the string value)
//  and then pass it in as a function parameter

var result = myFunction('Abc02023')
console.log('result = ', result)

function myFunction(str) {

    str  = str.toUpperCase();

   // Nicer syntax for defining regular expression.

    var pattern = /\*/g;

    str = str.replace(pattern, '');

    //  Unnecesarry use of regular expressions. Let's use trim instead
    //   to clean leading and trailing whitespace at once.

    str = str.trim()

    // let's return our result so the rest of the program can use it

    // return str
}
```

Last go round. We can make this much shorter and easier to read by chaining together all the modifications to `str`. And let's also give our function a useful name and try it out against a bad string.

```
var cleanString1 = toCleanedCaps('Abc02023')
var cleanString2 = toCleanedCaps(' ** test * ')

console.log('cleanString1 = ', cleanString1)
console.log('cleanString2 = ', cleanString2)

function toCleanedCaps(str) {
    return str
        .toUpperCase()
        .replace(/\\*/g, '')
        .trim()
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Will look into recent learning materials and into the book series.

Comment: sorry, but `.replace('\*', '')` is not the same as `.replace(/\*/g, '')` (which is what the original code is doing ... replace(string, value) replaces a single `*` ... the escape char before `*` is *not even relevant in your code* ... compare `'1*2*3'.replace('\*', '')` with '1*2*3'.replace('*', '') - no difference between those two, now compare with `'1*2*3'.replace(/\*/g, '')` (the original result)

Comment: You're right @JaromandaX. I really made a mess of that bit. I misread the regex, used incorrect string for what I thought I wanted to match, and also removed global matching functionality. Wow! Sorry about that brain fart. Updated to use regex again for global match of `*`.

Answer (score 0):

@skylize answer is close

what is equivalent to your code is actually

```
function toCleanedCaps(str) {
    return str
        .toUpperCase()
        .replace(/\*/g, '') // he got this wrong
        .trim()
}
```

Comment: Ok..I haven't read that far...will implement both the codes and understand the difference..

Answer (score -1):

Let's go over the statements one by one

```
document.str.value  = document.str.value.toUpperCase();
```

makes the string uppercase

```
pattern = new RegExp("\\*", "g");
document.str.value = document.str.value.replace(pattern, "");
```

replaces between zero and unlimited occurences of  the \ character , so no match in this case.

```
document.str.value = document.str.value.replace(/^\s+/, "");
```

replaces any whitespace character occurring between one and unlimited times at the beginning of the string, so no match.

```
document.str.value = document.str.value.replace(/\s+$/, "");
```

replaces any whitespace character occurring between one and unlimited times at the end of the string, so no match.

You are right. With `"Abc02023"` as input, the output is what you suggest.

Comment: `replaces between zero and unlimited occurences of the \ character` no .. `new RegExp('\\*', 'g')` is equal to `/\*/g` ... which would replace ALL occurrences of `*` with `''`